# Reading a Bash variable from a multiline Here Document

Tags: bash

What is the *perfect* way to read a multiline variable from a Here Document in Bash?

Look at how my way of doing it has the side-effect of returning `1` as `$?`...

---

#### Bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Unsetting...\n"
unset variable
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?"
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"

printf "\n"

printf "Setting to 'foo'...\n"
variable='foo'
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?"
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"

printf "\n"

printf "Setting to 'bar' by reading stdin from process substitution...\n"
read variable < <(echo 'bar')
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?"
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"

printf "\n"

printf "Setting to 'baz' by reading stdin from Here String...\n"
here_string='baz'
read variable <<< "${here_string}"
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?"
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"

printf "\n"

printf "Setting to 'quux' by reading stdin from Here Document...\n"
read variable <<- 'EOF'
quux
EOF
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?"
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"

printf "\n"

printf "Setting to 'thud <newline> thud' by reading stdin from Here Document...\n"
read -d '' variable <<- 'EOF'
thud
thud
EOF
printf "Exit status: %s.\n" "$?" # ONE?!one!!oneone? :)
printf "Variable: %s.\n" "${variable}"
```

---

#### Output

```
Unsetting...
Exit status: 0.
Variable: .

Setting to 'foo'...
Exit status: 0.
Variable: foo.

Setting to 'bar' by reading stdin from process substitution...
Exit status: 0.
Variable: bar.

Setting to 'baz' by reading stdin from Here String...
Exit status: 0.
Variable: baz.

Setting to 'quux' by reading stdin from Here Document...
Exit status: 0.
Variable: quux.

Setting to 'thud <newline> thud' by reading stdin from Here
Document...
Exit status: 1.
Variable: thud
thud.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` returns 1 when it reaches EOF, at the same time as assigning the last result read. This is why files that don't end with a newline are problematic, because a simple loop with `read` will not run the loop body for the final line.

When you use `read -d ''` without putting a NUL byte into the input, this is just like reading the last line of a file. The question is why would you ever want `read` to return 0 in this case? It's doing just like it should. Also note that heredocs (and herestrings) always add a newline to the end automatically.

Somewhat related:

- [My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21)
- Probably the next question you'll have: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-11/msg00148.html

Comment: What a wonderful insight I had no idea about: `while read l; do echo $l; done < <(printf "a\nb")` prints `a` and not `a b`!! This is so useful to know.. and I never noticed it!! And pre-empting my next question is just so awesome! You rock!

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that `read` is seeing end-of-file before it sees an ASCII NUL character. However, if that were true, the following should exit with 0:

```
read -d '' variable <<< $'thud\nthud\x00'
```

but it doesn't.

In lieu of a real fix, I can offer the following hack. Since it prevents any command from actually returning 0, it shouldn't break your login script:

```
read -d '' variable <<-'EOF' || true
thud
thud
EOF
```

`read` still exits 1, but this merely causes the shell to execute the `true` command, which is guaranteed to exit 0.

Comment: I upvoted. You are so resourceful in your hacks and kind in sharing your VAST knowledge, @chepner! Question: is there any reason why you wrote `\x00` as you did? Hex? I saw `\0` from time to time.. but never `\x00`.. Any adv/disadv to either method? Are they the same thing, actually?

Comment: Incidentally.. I like your hack but you yourself admit to not knowing the reason behind this.. (I liked your "test of my own assumptions" BTW) let's way for a potential full answer before awarding the question?

Comment: You cannot expand a nul byte from `$'...'`. `$'\0'`, `$'\x00'`, and `''`, are all equivalent. Check your heredoc with `od` and you should just see a file with a newline.

Comment: I never (ever) understood `$'...'` expansions.. care to explain or point me to some doc? Which of the 7 expansion type is this?

Comment: @Robottinosino They are identical to single-quotes, except expand escapes as in C string literals. The next version of POSIX will include this expansion. They're currently supported by Bash, Zsh, every Ksh variant...

Answer (score 3):

`read` will return nonzero if it reaches the end of a file without hitting its delimiter. Apparently \0 is treated as EOF whether it's your delimiter or not. One hack to prevent this would be to choose an unlikely delimiter and pad your string with it at the end. Example:

```
read -r -d $'\3' variable <<<"thud\nthud\n"$'\3' ; echo $?
```

That said, however, this is harder to do in a heredoc.

Comment: Yeah.. it seems like the question is not so trivial after all.. _difficult_ to do this in a heredoc without getting the pesky `1`.. Intriguing!

Comment: `\0` isn't treated as EOF. What gave you that idea?

Comment: @ormaaj: What I mean is this: Normally when `read` hits your defined delimiter it halts and returns a successful code. If it never hits your delimiter and reaches the end of input it will return failure. When your delimiter is `\0` it will halt and return failure when it sees `\0` as if it had reached the end of input and not your delimiter (actually, it hit both, but the `\0` will be treated like the end of input case. Admittedly my wording above was rather unclear.

Comment: No, it will only return failure when it really reaches the end of the file. The issue in this case is they never put a `\0` into the input, so the entire input is read and returns 1 as expected. If there were a NUL byte, it wouldn't have returned 1. That's what makes it possible to read a `\0`-delimited list. Perhaps you're confused because NULs will also give the appearance of truncating strings in Bash, because Bash uses C strings internally to represent everything.

Comment: You'd think so, but explain why `read -d '' a <<<one$'\0'two ; echo $?` returns 1. It should return 0 when \0 is encountered just like e.g. `read -d $'\3' a <<<one$'\3'two ; echo $?` does.

Comment: @Sorpigal that fails because bash can't represent `one$'\0'two` as a string, and thus it gets truncated internally to `one` (see @ormaaj's comment above about bash using C strings).  Try the same thing using a file instead of a herestring.

Comment: @JoshCartwright Right. What's more, Bash here(doc|string)s _are_ files. Consequently, it's impossible to put a `\0` into a herestring unless you do: `{ printf 'one\0two' >/dev/fd/0; IFS= read -rd '' x; } <<<''`. The easy way to demonstrate is to just use a pipe instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the here-document into an array with `mapfile` or its alias `readarray`

```
mapfile var <<-'EOF'
thud
thud
EOF
```

resulting in

```
var=([0]="thud
" [1]="thud
")
```

and then just concatenate the array elements e.g.

```
variable=${var[0]}
variable+=${var[1]}
...
```

For arrays of variable length you can do this in a loop or use the `printf` builtin function (thanks to eush77):

```
printf -v variable "%s" "${var[@]}"
```

both options result in

```
variable=$'thud\nthud\n'
```

The reason why the exit status was 1 was already given by Sorpigal ..

Comment: Instead of a loop, you can concatenate arrays with `variable=$(printf "%s" "${var[@]}")`

Comment: true.. or use `printf -v variable "%s" "${var[@]}"` to write it directly to the variable.. thanks for pointing this out ;)

Comment: Great! Didn't know about `printf -v`.