# Bash backtick escaping

Tags: bash

Is this Bash variable declaration statement:

```
foo='b'`    `'ar'
```

less *efficient* than this:

```
foo='bar'
```

Does this way of formatting "hanging" or "aligned" indents (line continuations):

```
a_long_variable_name='a seemingly infinitely long '`
                    `'string requiring continuatio'`
                    `'n on the next line...'
```

spawn sub-shells, waste resources, or affect performance in any way, apart from
annoying those who dislike its form for (anti?)readability?

Efficiency as in: *computer* efficiency, not "humans typing many characters and creating space-based, gratuitous maintenance debt".

Can impact (or lack thereof) on performance be easily demonstrated?

Comment: I can't help but think that if you're concerned about performance and using a bash script, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ï wanted to argue against or in favour of a _coding convention_ that, if it results in useless inefficiencies which can be demonstrated, has no reason for being. Do you actually know if the backticks "cost" cycles? That's a simple, straightforward question which I am not able to _demonstrate_ one way or the other..

Comment: According to [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), backticks are evaluated in a subshell, which is almost certainly going to cost you (in terms of computational cycles).

Comment: A certain type of parser could look inside the backticks, realise there are no tokens and could collapse the whole thing to a no-op, couldn't it? I think it was reasonable to wonder..

Comment: See also [Bash variable concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537884/bash-variable-concatenation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tester1() {
  for i in {1..1000}; do
    a_long_variable_name='a seemingly infinitely long '`
                        `'string requiring continuation'`
                        `'on the next line...'
    echo $a_long_variable_name > tmp 
  done
}

tester2() {
  for i in {1..1000}; do
    a_long_variable_name="a seemingly infinitely long\
string requiring continuation\
on the next line..."
    echo $a_long_variable_name > tmp 
  done
}

echo tester1
time tester1
echo tester2
time tester2
```

**Results**

```
tester1

real    0m1.878s
user    0m0.209s
sys     0m0.566s

tester2

real    0m0.335s
user    0m0.026s
sys     0m0.078s
```

These all have similar timings to case 2:

```
read -r -d '' a_long_variable_name <<EOF
    a seemingly infinitely long
    string requiring continuation
    on the next line...
EOF

a_long_variable_name="a seemingly infinitely long\
                      string requiring continuation\
                      on the next line..."
```

Comment: Perfect answer! :) So, I guess the backtick escaping is costly indeed.. (a smart look-ahead tokenizer could have nulled that out, am I mistaken?) How would you achieve the same without the backticks? With plain backslash, as in tester2? (indenting would be nice..)

Comment: It might be that bash is optimizing this somehow. What do you mean the same?

Comment: A) If Bash spawned the subshell (that's what it does, right?) upon encountering the backtick, it would mean wasted cycles no matter what; if it looked _inside_ the backticks and realised there were no _tokens_ it could "swallow and discard" the whole thing as a no-op. 2) With `the same` I meant: Python-like column-aligned indents after line continuations. It's a code formatting convention debate for long strings.. What would you do in that case?

Comment: updated the answer, I mostly use heredocs myself. I agree, the backtick overhead makes no sense, should be optimized away.

Comment: Your suggested "alternatives" are not really that same as my original, even if I thank you for expanding your answer! Look.. you are adding extra blanks where there were none..

Comment: Oh I see, I thought I made a copy/paste mistake with the `continuatio`. I never had to squeeze text that strictly :)

Comment: There is an option with here docs (`<<-`) which discards leading TABs, but doesn't work, for what I can see, with plain-old spaces.. or, does it?

Comment: @Robottinosino, this is a very good question. I think your backtick thing is a very good solution. I will def look into this and will update if I can find a better way. I tried all sorts of things (sed, echo, heredocs) but can't find a fast way to handle word splits.

Comment: Note that the `read` example causes `read` to exit with status 1, which could cause problems if you are running with `set -e`.

Comment: I do note that, I asked this in the past as well :) -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421331/reading-a-bash-variable-from-a-multiline-here-document

Answer (score 0):

If I needed it, I'd probably build up the string thus:

```
x='a seemingly infinitely long '
x="$x"'string requiring continuatio'
x="$x"'n on the next line...'

a_long_variable_name="$x"
```

Or minor variations on that theme.  Or I'd repeat the long variable name on each line.  Here's a real script I use — it lists relevant environment variables for me:

```
informix1="DB[^=]|DELIMIDENT=|SQL|ONCONFIG|TBCONFIG|INFOR"
informix2="CLIENT_LOCALE=|GL_|GLS8BITSYS|CC8BITLEVEL|ESQL|FET_BUF_SIZE="
informix3="INF_ROLE_SEP=|NODEFDAC=|ONCONFIG|OPTCOMPIND|PDQ|PSORT"
informix4="PLCONFIG|SERVER_LOCALE|FGL|C4GL|NE_"
informix5="TCL_LIBRARY|TK_LIBRARY|TERM=|TERMCAP=|TERMINFO="
informix="$informix1|$informix2|$informix3|$informix4|$informix5"
system1="COLLCHAR=|LANG=|LC_"
system2="(DY)?LD_LIBRARY_PATH(_[63][42])?=|PATH=|SHLIB_PATH=|LIBPATH="
system="$system1|$system2"
jlss="IX([A-Z]|D(32|64)?)="

env |
${EGREP:-egrep} "^($informix|$system|$jlss)" |
sort
```

(And the ability to switch which `egrep` program to use became necessary when Mac OS X 10.7.x `egrep` stopped working on the expression because it was 'too big'.)

Comment: Dear Jonathan, I personally find it easier, in Bash, to read constant values within single quotes. The double quotes already tell me "watch out for expansions in here". My "brain parser" can relax when I see a single quote. Other, of course, will disagree.. actually preferring the _consistency_ of always using double quotes..